# Time Complexity Checking

Tags: time, complexity-theory

What would you say the time complexity of this function is?
I think its O(logN), but can you verify? If not is it possible to make it LogN?
I am trying to count the amount of shifts on a rotated array

```
    int findRotationCount(int A[], int sizeOfArray) //O(logN)
    {
        int countOfShift = 0, i;
        for (i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; ++i)
        {
            ++countOfShift;
            if (i+1 == sizeOfArray)
                break;;
            if (A[i] > A[i+1])
                break;
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `O(N)` for me, where `N` is your `sizeOfArray` value.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is `O(n)`, where `n=sizeOfArray`. Here's the proof:

Your loop can end if at least one of the following conditions is met:

1. `i=n` => There were `n` iterations, and therefore, complexity of your function is `O(n)`.
2. `A[i] > A[i+1]` => There exists a member in the array, that is greater than the next one. Here you will have to think about the worst case for your function. For this one, it is an array sorted in increasing order.That means that you will iterate through the array from the first to the last member and never find this second condition met. So, in the worst case, complexity is `O(n)`.

Since your function ends when at least one of the conditions 1 and two is met, and we've proven that in both cases complexity is O`(n)`, then you can say that complexity of the function is also `O(n)`.
Note that this was worst case analysis.